# VLC authentication using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, httpwebrequest, vlc

I'm trying to use VLC's HTTP interface to read the current playlist (`GET /requests/playlist.xml`).

This was working fine in an older version of VLC, but in recent versions they added a password option and then made it mandatory.  (There is no username.)

I first tried using this:

```
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("", password);
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
```

However this resulted in a WebException reporting a 401 error.  Snooping the traffic revealed that it sent one request that did not have the Authorization header, and then immediately reported the error without attempting to actually authenticate.  (VLC did correctly respond with the WWW-Authenticate challenge.)

If I specify a non-blank username, then it sends the same request as before but then follows up with a second request that does specify the Authorization header -- which then fails because VLC rejects the username.

I finally managed to get it to work by setting the header explicitly:

```
var credential = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(":" + password));
request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + credential;
```

This seems like something that should have worked originally, though.  Is this a bug in .NET (or WinInet), that it can't cope with blank usernames; or is it a bug in VLC, that it doesn't use a username; or is it a bug in my code, that I needed to set something else?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, albeit I'm using an empty string for a password. There are tools such as [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) you can use to decompile .NET libraries you are using so you can view their source code. Although I haven't found anything, maybe you can use this to determine if it's a .NET issue. I've had this problem occur using both Basic and Digest authorization so I'd take a look at HttpWebRequest (which I assume you are using).

It seems setting the Authorization header manually is the way to go for now. Since you are using Basic, if you care about the security of your password, you might want to look into SSL if you aren't implementing it already.